# How to create background services for local notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, notifications

I am trying to create local notifications for my iOS application based on JSON new data.

I have created web services and parsing some datas and store into plist as a string at first time.
I want to parse JSON at every n minutes once and compare with plist stored data for anything newly arrived datas or not. 
If anything newly arrived I want to show notification.

Those process want to do application active and background both times without any hanging.

Thanks,

Comment: you can use silent push notification to achieve this.

Comment: How can I do silent notification?

Comment: check the answer,i had posted it

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not support these kind of background service. The reason being that they drain the battery and therefor give the user a bad experience. You might want to implement it serverside.

Apple only allows background running for apps that fall the in following categories: VOIP, audio streaming, location and accessory (bluetooth).

Comment: Hi, Please give some solution above mentioned process. I want to create local notification based on JSON data.

Comment: Well you can't, at least not the background, unless you app falls in on of the background categories. Server side with push notification is you best option.

Comment: how to parse JSON every five minutes?

Comment: In you app when it is active just use an `NSTimer` in the background this is not possible.

Comment: Yes while you app is on the foreground you will be able to use a timer.

Comment: This is easily found in the documentation or other stack overflow question. Where are not here to write you code. You should really some a bit more self initiative .

Comment: you mean if I have the correct background categories, e.g. I can fire a local notification from didUpdateLocations while app is in background?

Comment: Yes, if you set your background mode to location tracking you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update data from the server in the background, you basically have 2 options:

- Use background fetch. The system will launch your app into the background in specific intervals (*which are not entirely under your control*!) and give it the chance to download (have a look at [this post](http://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/) for a good intro).
- Use (silent) push notifications. This of course requires work on the backend-side.

Which one you should use depends on things like

- Whether you have control over the backend (if not, you can't send push notifications)
- How often the data is updated. If it's updated very often, background fetch might be ok. If it's updated very infrequently or irregularly, then push might be superior.

Comment: I can confirm that ask a background fetch every 5 min will mostly not be granted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Silent Push Notifications,if Push notification serve your purpose.It doesn't come in notification tray.

1.As soon as when notification comes , Below method is called,overide this method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    NSLog("Download From Remote Notification%@",userInfo)
}
```

[image]

2.Enable Remote notification

**No user Interaction is needed in silent push notification**

Here is good article which explains step by step guide

http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications